# Can I use 4x4 post bases to install a 6’ fence across the top of a wood deck?

Tags: wood, fence, post

I have recently installed a fence around the outside perimeter of the deck to hide a pool. My deck covers my back yard area and is on the ground. I want to run a fence across the deck to fully enclose the pool. The fence doesn’t have to be 6’ but at minimum 4’. I didn’t want to cut the deck boards and dig holes, so I thought maybe this would be a solid second option, however I did not know if it would work. The fence only has to be tall enough & covered enough to prevent kids from getting through easily. It will be roughly 20’ long. Edit: the deck is on the ground, meaning it has joists sitting on blocks.

Comment: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-12-Gauge-Black-Powder-Coated-E-Z-Base-FPBB44/100655350 This is similar to what I was looking at to secure the posts to the deck.

Comment: Might help if you add a picture.  Lots of information missing.  Deck is on the ground, does this mean the deck boards are just sitting on pt sleepers or do you have posts in concrete blocks or do you have joists sitting on bricks.

Comment: If it is a wire fence you can, if it is wood fence (boards) you can not

Comment: @Ruskes  Are you thinking the wind force would be too much with wood?  Most wire/woven fences I know of required to be stretched to be good.  OP wants to prevent kids going though it.

Comment: @MD_Moe it looks like you may have accidentally created another account. See the [help center](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) for help merging these so you can edit your own posts easily.

Answer (score 2):

These footings need to be bolted to a firm foundation to support a fence post enough to keep it standing.

If you screw it to a deck it'll just rip the boards off the first time someone leans on it.

If you can drill through the deck and bolt it to the deck foundation (if the foundation is strong enough) that could work (all-thread can come in handy).  If not, you're going to need braces to keep it standing. Put these stays on the pool side so they can't be climbed to gain access to the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your wood deck has 3/4 thick boards, it becomes questionable if you can just screw in the fence post holders.

The one you are looking at Home Depot, needs 4 inch long screws (anchors) to screw into concrete.

If you have concrete base that is at least 4 inch, preferably 6 inch then you can install your wood fence.

Alternative would be to use Chainlink fence that does not need wind resistant installation.

Comment: generally pool fences need to be of a non-climbable type.

Comment: Wiring an extension cord to the chain link would take care of that, @Jasen! :) :D :) :D

Comment: @Jasen prisons use chainlink fences

Comment: I guess you can add razor wire and machine guns then...  but seriously if this fence is to keep small chidren out of the pool, they are the ones with feet the right size to climb chain link fences.